# Using Special Characters in Email

Tags: html, email, gmail

A recent email that was sent out of my organization included an em-dash `&mdash;` character. However, Gmail appears to demote this character to a hyphen. En-dashes seem to show up okay, too.

I also tried a range of other characters but it seems like the em-dash is the only one with problems.

Is there a way to get an em-dash to appear correctly in Gmail? Are there other characters that won't appear correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Google classify all of it into just a normal hyphen.

Quoted from the website:

> Notes from Google: Google treats hyphens, en dashes, and em dashes as
>   the same character, translating them all into “–”. Neither the en nor
>   the em appear on standard keyboards making them even harder to use.

http://www.pcwizardsinc.com/home/googleappsgmail-insertingen-dashorem-dashes